# Dynamic row and static column array for 'write line' loop

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I need to generate an array for a 'write line' custom function.  This function writes a single row of cells (the array) to a text file during a loop.
This array is static in size.
The row to be written to the text file is 'detected' by the Rng variable below:

```
Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(5).Find(userform1.ComboBox1.Value)
```

i.e. the Rng variable only indexes a single cell in column 5 - as matched by the value in ComboBox1. The array to be written by writeLine will be column 6:49 of the row matched by Rng.

The arguments for the 'write line' function are

1. the value of the combobox i.e. `userform1.combobox1.value`, and
2. the array to be written in the 'write line' function

So far, I have this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton18_Click()

Dim Range As Range
Dim Array As Range

Set Range =      Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(5).Find(userform1.ComboBox1.Value) ''anticipated to set the row index of the array???

Array = ????

Function.writeLine(userform1.ComboBox1.Value,????)

End Sub
```

The trouble I am having is to create an array that incorporates the changing row whilst having the number of columns fixed?

Here is part of the writeLine function:

```
Do Until objTF.AtEndOfStream
    readString = objTF.readline
    data = Split(readString, vbTab)
    foundID = data(0)
    If StrComp(**foundID, ID**, 1) <> 0 Then
        objTF2.writeLine (readString)
    ElseIf StrComp(**foundID, ID**, 1) = 0 Then
        'write initial value outside the loop
        strTmp = Split(readString, strDelim)
        'Modify the data array to include the data provided by writeArray
        For argPos = 5 To UBound(data)
            'check for index out of bounds, stop writing if it is!
            If (argPos - 5) > UBound(writeArray) Then Exit For 'need to check this will exit if the value is index out of bounds.
            data(argPos) = writeArray(dataPos)
            dataPos = dataPos + 1
        Next argPos
        'Take each entry from data and build a string delimited by strDelim
        Do Until counter > UBound(data)
            resultStr = IIf(counter <= UBound(data), resultStr & data(counter) & strDelim, resultStr & data(counter))
            counter = counter + 1
        Loop
        'output to temp file
        objTF2.writeLine (resultStr)...
```

Basically, the "foundID" and "ID" are the variables to be matched in order to write the array to the text file.  The "ID" is the ComboBox1.value.  "foundID" is the value in column 5 of the spreadsheet.  Column 6:49 (the array) are to be written to the text file.

Comment: Could you provide some example as inputs

Answer (score 0):

Use Ubound to get the range as array.

Private Sub CommandButton18_Click()

```
Dim rRange As Range
Dim colno As Long
Dim rownumber As Long
Dim sString As String

    lastrow = 10

For colno = 6 To 43
   For rownumber = 1 To lastrow
       sString = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(rownumber, colno)
       Next rownumber
    Next
```

End Sub

Comment: Thanks newjenn.  I did not explain my problem accurately first time round (lack of vba knowledge).  The row is not dynamic as stated earlier.  The array is static.  What changes is the row selection...

Comment: Then your code not require for loop, you can pass rRange(rowselectionvalue,columnvalue)

Comment: Ok, reading my problem maybe I did not explain the problem properly again.  The rRange variable only indexes a single cell in column 5 - as matched by the value in ComboBox1.  The array to be written by writeLine will be column 6:49 of the row matched by rRange.  does that make sense?

Comment: What is your input to write line?  for example Rrange will fetch row from user, that row need to be input to the writeline function

Comment: I have added code to my original question.  Hopefully it will help.

Comment: These are the function inputs: 'Function writeLine(ID As String, writeArray() As String) As Boolean'.  ID is the Combobox value, writeArray is the array that I am trying to create.

Comment: Is writearray() is 1D or 2D. What the array contains? I couldnt understand column 6:49 what it mean? is array need to get value from rRange value.?

Comment: For Example Is Writearray(rowvalue, columnvalue) from rRange? if so ,

Comment: I don't think you need to write the contents of the cells in columns 6:49 (F:AW) to an array to write to a text file. Couldn't you just loop through them and create a string out of them? Something like `For i = 1 to 44 string = string & range.offset(0,i)`

Comment: writearray() is 2D. 1 row, 43 columns.  Each column will have either a "1" or "" depending on a condition (not stated here).  If I understand correctly, Writearray(rowvalue, columnvalue) where rowvalue changes for each loop of write line function, and columnvalue is the range of columns F:BA.

Comment: row number start from ?

Comment: @Kyle - i think the writeLine function writes each element of the (desired) array to a string variable, element-by-element and separated by vbtab.  The string variable is then written to the text file.  So I need to provide the function with the reference range/array with which it compiles the string variable with.  My difficulty is to provide this reference range/array.  newjenn - the row number starts from rRange (rRange references a row within column 5, and the row ranges depending on the value of comboBox1 in the userform)

Comment: @so first, we need to find the starting row and ending row, Inorder to finalize the row range. will rRange contains both the range?

Comment: @alex123456789 I guess my point is, I would skip the array all together, so directly with a string, and write to the file that way. Why bother with an array, particularly passing an array, when it isn't necessary?

Comment: @ Kyle - Thanks for the comment.  We are trying to add functionality to code already in use.  To avoid global changes, we just want to adjust our code to fit in.